# Dealing with cursor with controlled contenteditable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable, caret

I'm trying to set up a controlled `contentEditable` in React. Every time i write something in the div the component re-renders, and the cursor/caret jumps back to the beginning. I'm trying to deal with this by saving the cursor in an `onInput` callback:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
    const [HTML, setHTML] = useState()
    const [selectionRange, setSelectionRange] = useState()
    console.log('on rerender:', selectionRange)

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        console.log('in layout effect', selectionRange)
        const selection = document.getSelection()
        if (selectionRange !== undefined) {
            selection.removeAllRanges()
            selection.addRange(selectionRange)
        }
    })

    function inputHandler(ev) {
        console.log('on input', document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0))
        setSelectionRange(document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange())
        setHTML(ev.target.innerHTML)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div
                contentEditable
                suppressContentEditableWarning
                onInput={inputHandler}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: HTML }}
            >
            </div>
            <div>html:{HTML}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

This doesn't work, the cursor is still stuck at the beginning. If I input one character in the `contentEditable` div, i get the output:

```
on input 
Range { commonAncestorContainer: #text, startContainer: #text, startOffset: 1, endContainer: #text
, endOffset: 1, collapsed: true }
on rerender: 
Range { commonAncestorContainer: #text, startContainer: #text, startOffset: 1, endContainer: #text
, endOffset: 1, collapsed: true }
in layout effect 
Range { commonAncestorContainer: div, startContainer: div, startOffset: 0, endContainer: div, endOffset: 0, collapsed: true }
```

Why does the value of `selectionRange` change in the `useLayoutEffect` callback, when it was correct at the start of the re-render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `contentEditable` div is re-rendered it disappears. The `Range` object contains references to the children of this div (`startNode`, `endNode` properties), and when the div disappears the `Range` object tracks this , and resets itself to it's parent, with zero offset.

The code below demonstrates how to deal with this if you now that the `contentEditable` div will only have one child. It fixes the problem where the cursor gets stuck at the beginning. What we do is to save the offset in the text, and when restoring we create a new `Range` object, with the newly rendered text node as `startNode` and our saved offset as `startOffset`.

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
    const [HTML, setHTML] = useState()
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState()
    const textRef = useRef()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (offset !== undefined) {
            const newRange = document.createRange()
            newRange.setStart(textRef.current.childNodes[0], offset)
            const selection = document.getSelection()
            selection.removeAllRanges()
            selection.addRange(newRange)
        }
    })

    function inputHandler(ev) {
        const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)
        setOffset(range.startOffset)
        setHTML(ev.target.innerHTML)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div
                contentEditable
                suppressContentEditableWarning
                onInput={inputHandler}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: HTML }}
                ref={textRef}
            >
            </div>
            <div>html:{HTML}</div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Hi, how to do it if the div will have multiple childs?

Comment: @snowape this brings error when there's a line break, do you know how to set range with list of Nodes

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm not familiar with the range operation, but seems to me the problem lies in the state change.

You can use `useRef` or `useState` to fix this, let me use an object with `useState` for now.

```
  function App() {
    const [HTML, setHTML] = useState()
    const [selectionRange, setSelectionRange] = useState({ range: null })

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const selection = document.getSelection()
        if (selectionRange !== undefined) {
            selection.removeAllRanges()
            if (selectionRange.range) 
              selection.addRange(selectionRange.range)
        }
    })

    function inputHandler(ev) {
        selectionRange.range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneRange())
        setSelectionRange({ ...selectionRange })
        setHTML(ev.target.innerHTML)
    }
```

You can easily replace this version with a `useRef`, the point is to make sure the value is assigned right away before going through the `setState` which takes time to get your state updated to the latest value.

Comment: I tried your idea to save the range immediately before setting it with `setSelectionRange`. Now the selection gets reset to zero already at the beginning of render "on rerender", and cursor is still stuck. Thanks for trying.

Comment: let me ask you something. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to make sure the cursor follows the typing, so this is a typing software on screen, something like that? just curious.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: I experiment with your code, here's the codepen https://codepen.io/windmaomao/pen/wvemxOG?editors=1111. If i remove `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, it works. But of course i still don't know what you expect, because with your code you can't type in HTML in the div.

Comment: The idea is to have a controlled contentEditable div the same way you might have a controlled textarea. Changing the html in the div can be done by changing the `HTML` state variable. This way you can intercept the user input and clean up the html.

Comment: i see. in this case, i think you have the `onInput`, and you don't need to set the state back. Instead, whenever you need  to access the html or content, just use the `html` you received. This way you don't need to deal with the internal of this input, treating  it as a black box. Let me know if there's any task you can't do with this approach.